# show multi file upload based on dropdown select

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to run this code but I don't know why error comes with jquery when I select any item in the list 
here is the code

```
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <td> // green underline in this line of the <td>
            <select name="one" onchange=" 
if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '1')
{
    document.myform['b'].style.visibility = 'visible'
}
else if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '2')
{
    document.myform['b'].style.visibility = 'visible',
    document.myform['m'].style.visibility = 'visible'
}
else if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '3') 
{
    document.myform['b'].style.visibility = 'visible',
    document.myform['m'].style.visibility = 'visible',
    document.myform['p'].style.visibility = 'visible'
}
else
{
    document.myform['b'].style.visibility = 'hidden',
    document.myform['m'].style.visibility = 'hidden',
    document.myform['p'].style.visibility = 'hidden'
} ;">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">Bachelore Degree</option>
                <option value="2">Master Degree</option>
                <option value="3">PhD</option>
            </select>
            <input type="file" id ="b" style="visibility:hidden;" />
            <input type="file" id ="m" style="visibility:hidden;" />
            <input type="file" id ="p" style="visibility:hidden;" />
        </td>
    </table>
</form>​
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.jsl")
}
```

if I select 1 or 2 or 3 from drop down list then I get this error message

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'b' of undefined or null reference

the idea behind the code is if the user selected his qualification as bachelor degree holder only one file he has to upload and when he select master then 2 files to upload and for phd 3 files certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your html/js code and didn't see the errors as you mentioned.

However I have slightly restructured your code by placing the 'onchange' js code in a seperate method as it adds clarity. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function qualificationSelected(selectedIndex){
    document.getElementById('b').style.visibility = (selectedIndex >= 1) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('m').style.visibility = (selectedIndex >= 2) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('p').style.visibility = (selectedIndex == 3) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> 
            <select name="one" onchange="qualificationSelected(this.selectedIndex)">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">Bachelore Degree</option>
                <option value="2">Master Degree</option>
                <option value="3">PhD</option>
            </select>
            <input type="file" id ="b" style="visibility:hidden;" />
            <input type="file" id ="m" style="visibility:hidden;" />
            <input type="file" id ="p" style="visibility:hidden;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>​

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In html it is working fine, but I am using MVC sample ASP NET so I couldn't run it , your code is working fine but when i add the label in same class form-group with the same file input labels shows even if I change property of the function on load to hidden any idea ???????? anyhow will make your answer as correct

Comment: how can i add the selected item to the model variable something like @html.hiddenfor(model=>model.degree = the selected item from the dropdownlist)